# Notation for jet bundles of mixed order?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, oc.optimization-and-control, jets

This question is motivated by the consideration of linear control systems in Brunovsky normal form.  The idea is that you have $m$ smooth functions with unconstrained dynamics, and the control input for the $i$th function $z^i(t)$ is the $r_i$th derivative of the function.  This leads to the control system
\begin{align*} \dot{z}^i_k & = z^i_{k+1}, \qquad 0 \leq k \leq r_i - 2, \ \ 1 \leq i \leq m, \\
\dot{z}^i_{r_i-1} & = u^i, \qquad 1 \leq i \leq m,
\end{align*}
where $u^1, \ldots, u^m$ are the controls.

This ODE system naturally lives on a space that is obtained from $J^1(\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{R}^m)$ with its standard contact structure by prolonging each of the contact forms
$$ \theta^i_0 = dz^i_0 - z^i_1\, dt $$
$(r_i-1)$ times.  So here's the question: If all the $r_i$ are equal to the same value $r$, the underlying manifold of the resulting prolongation is just the $r$th-order jet space, denoted $J^r(\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{R}^m)$.  But is there a standard name/notation for this space when the orders $r_i$ are not all the same?